# MySQL SELECT query get record if is_default = 1 otherwise is_default = 0?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My image table look like this:

```
id     product_id     image         is_default

1      11             test.jpg      0
2      11             make.jpg      0
3      11             tkae.jpg      1
4      11             value.jpg     0
5      11             mcate.jpg     0
```

I want to fetch a default image if `is_default` 1 is not exists the fetch first image. I try this query but not success.

```
SELECT *
FROM `images`
WHERE `product_id` = '11'
GROUP BY `product_id`
ORDER BY `is_default` DESC
```

Can anyone help me to write that query.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler

```
SELECT *
FROM `images`
WHERE `product_id` = '11'
ORDER BY `is_default` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

should work.